# How bad is Coq proving both $T$ and $\lnot T$?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-assistants, coq

> Question: How bad is Coq proving both $T$ and $\lnot T$? Can it be abused?

Back in 2011 on the coq-club mailing list there was a thread:
[Is the Daniel Schepler's inconsistency real?](https://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/hLJinlsU/is-the-daniel-schepler-s-inconsistency-real).
In the thread Georgi Guninski is me.

Inline in it there are two files (*file 1*) and (*file 2*),
which are minor modifications of Daniel's code.

In 2023 all of the following can be proved based on the files.

1. $T$
2. $\lnot T$.
3. Taking $T$ as axiom, we can prove $False$.
4. Taking $\lnot T$ as axiom, we can prove $False$.

Proving $T$ and $\lnot T$ doesn't lead to proof of $False$,
with a Coq error.

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/ ? From the linked thread it seems clear that this is a Coq quirk, and no one proved mathematics is inconsistent.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think this is related since there is MO question [How true are theorems proved by Coq?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59520/how-true-are-theorems-proved-by-coq?rq=1)

Comment: That question predates the existence of proofassistants.SE by several years.

Comment: Also: https://mathoverflow.net/q/63816/1946

Comment: I think this definitely belongs on https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com. I wish there was a way to vote to close for that reason...

Comment: @SamHopkins According to the FAQ, only question that are at most 60 days old can be migrated: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: but questions can be directly migrated to e.g. Math Stack Exchange by a closure option.

Comment: @SamHopkins Sorry, I got confused by a comment mentioning "several years" - but that was about a different question. Yes, this question (and any question less than 60 days old) can be migrated *by a moderator* to [proofassistants.se] - regular users can only choose one of the default paths. So if you think it should be migrated, you can flag for moderators attention (and ask the mods to do that) or open a discussion on meta, if you think that it's better to see first whether there is some community consensus about this.

Comment: I agree about asking on meta about migrating this.

Comment: A general question asking about migration to sites different from the sites listed among migration paths was now posted on meta: [How to recommend that a question is better suited for another SE site that isn't listed in the close reasons?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5746)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Based on the answer, Coq's proof of $T$ is not what human mathematician will expect? Coq's proof has additional constraints on the usage of $T$?

Answer (score 9):

Having read the Coq club conversation, I think your summary is slightly misleading. One can prove `T` with universe constraints `X`, and one can prove `~ T` with universe constraints `Y`, but the constraints `X` and `Y` are incompatible, which is why it is not possible to prove `T /\ ~ T`. (The Coq error is not a bug, it's a desired state of affairs.)

The main reason I think this presentation is misleading, is that the universe constraints are part of the statement, even if they are usually hidden from the user (because most of the time the user doesn't need to think about them). But they are still there! The given examples of `T` and `~ T` are not actually opposites of each other if you take the universe constraints into account. So everything is fine.

Comment: Very interesting; is this the same, in some sense, as different things being true in different set theoretical universes? (i.e. different underlying axiomatic systems)?

Comment: @AlecRhea: No. Universe constraints are an indexing scheme to avoid the type of all types paradox. Instead you have hierarchy $Type_0$ in $Type_1$ in $Type_2$... A simplified version of the issue is something like this: proof of $T$ requires that if $a$ is in $Type_n$ then $b$ must be in $Type_{n+1}$, but the proof of $\lnot T$ requires that if $b$ is in $Type_m$ then $a$ must be in $Type_{m+1}$. It's impossible to have both constraints at the same time.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Thanks. So Coq's proof of $T$ is not what human mathematician will expect? Coq's proof has additional constraints on the usage of $T$?

Comment: Just like certain theorems used by very human mathematicians (think the various adjoint functor theorems in category theory) have size conditions on universes of sets, this is also the case of the proofs of $T$ and $\sim T$ here. The fact that one can overlook these side conditions by not being precise about what one means when writing `Type` or "set" does not mean that "human mathematicians" would not have to consider these. And indeed, as this example shows, overlooking them has a dire impact on consistency, just like the adjoint functor theorem without size restrictions is simply not true.